# How can I navigate once when I found a JWT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am just getting stuck into react-native and need some help navigating to a protected screen when a token is found. Where should I look for a token on app load? And how can I navigate the user once without calling navigate multiple times? The problem I have is I am checking for a token on component mount, which is nested inside a stack. If I navigate to another part of the stack, the function is called again and I am unable to navigate. I can retrieve the token outside of the stack, but then I am having trouble navigating, as I need to pass props.navigate within a screen component. What is the recommended approach to finding a token, and making a navigation?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import RootContainer from './screens/RootContainer';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

RootContainer.js

...

```
  render() {

    const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
      main: {
        screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
          map: { screen: MapScreen },
          deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
          review: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
              review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
              settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
            })
          }
        })
      }
      // Route Configuration for Initial Tab Navigator
    }, {
      // do not instantly render all screens
      lazy: true,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarVisible: false
      }
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </View>
    );

  }
}
```

WelcomeScreen.js

...

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.checkForToken(); // async method 
}

// Async Action 
 export const checkForToken = () => async dispatch => {
   console.log("action - does token exist ?");
   let t = await AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt");
   if (t) {
     console.log("action - token exists");
     // Dispatch an action, login success
     dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: t });
   } else {
     return null;
   }
 }

// WelcomeScreen.js continued

componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
  this.authComplete(nextProps);
}

authComplete(props){
  if(props.token){
    props.navigation.navigate('map'); // called again and again when I try to navigate from within the Bottom Tab Bar Component 
  }
}

render(){
  if(this.props.appLoading){ // default True 
    return ( <ActivityIndicator />);
  }
  return ( <Text>WelcomeScreen</Text> );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.auth.token,
    appLoading: state.auth.appLoading // default True 
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(WelcomeScreen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, not to store navigation state in redux. 
Just navigate when you found a token or the user logged in.

If you still want to use redux or simply want to react on props changes, then the way is to use some Redirect Component, and render it only when the token changed from nothing to something. You could read about such implementation from react-router [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md). I think there is no such implementation for React Navigation.

When you are using React Navigation, then I would suggest to look into the docs, because I think it solves the problem you have. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: I think I somehow missed that createSwitchNavigator, thanks!